# Storing 10 decimal places in SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework-5, sql-server-2012, decimal

I have a decimal value in C# that I am using Entity Framework to write to a SQL Server database table (I'm using code first).  The C# value has 10 decimal places but since the column in the database is a decimal(18,2) only 2 of those decimal places are retained.  I'd like to store the entire value with all 10 decimal places.  How is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried changing the column to be a `numeric(26,10)`?

Comment: no because I'm using code first and therefore these changes must be done in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I fixed this was to add

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ExchangeRate>().Property(rate => rate.CurrencyRate).HasPrecision(12, 10);
modelBuilder.Entity<ExchangeRate>().Property(rate => rate.CurrencyInverseRate).HasPrecision(12, 10);
```

in my OnModelCreating method in the database context class.